# I need to use my Custom Class without some parameters

Tags: java, android, oop

I need to create objects from my custom class with and without some parameters, without getting the nullReference error.
My Class İs :

```
package upiynar.cback;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;

/**
 * Created by shock on 10/24/2017.
 */

public class  Haber {
    private String baslik;
    private String kisaAciklama;
    private String tarih;
    private String resimURL;

    public Haber(String baslik, String kisaAciklama, String tarih,String resimURL){
        super();
        this.baslik = baslik;
        this.kisaAciklama = kisaAciklama;
        this.tarih = tarih;
        this.resimURL = resimURL;
    }
    public String getBaslik(){
        return baslik;
    }
    public String getKisaAciklama(){
        return kisaAciklama;
    }
    public String getTarih(){
        return tarih;
    }
    public String getResimURL() {
        return resimURL;
    }
    public void setBaslik(String baslik){
        this.baslik = baslik;
    }
    public void setKisaAciklama(String kisaAciklama){
        this.kisaAciklama = kisaAciklama;
    }
    public void setTarih(String tarih){
        this.tarih = tarih;
    }
    public void setResimURL(String resimURL) {
        this.resimURL = resimURL;
    }
}
```

I want to add one more parameter to this class, something like :

```
public Haber(String baslik, String kisaAciklama, String tarih,String resimURL,String uzunAciklama){
    super();
    this.baslik = baslik;
    this.kisaAciklama = kisaAciklama;
    this.tarih = tarih;
    this.resimURL = resimURL;
    this.uzunAciklama = uzunAciklama;
```

The Problem is, i want to create 2 type of things from this class which will be like :

```
Haber("asdasda","asdasdsa","farfafa")  
Haber("asdasda","asdasdsa","farfafa","adfadsgsad")
```

But if i dont input the all attributes compiler gives NullReferenceError.What can i do about that ? I thought about creating a child class which will got a extra uzunAciklama string but i couldnt made that.

Comment: There isn't a constructor for class haber 'Haber("asdasda","asdasdsa","farfafa") ' for 3 parameter, or do I miss something?

Comment: I dont know what constructor is :/ Everything is here nothing miss.

Comment: if you don't pass the data then don't use it, overload the constructors and define default values of members as required

Comment: Should i mention it, I am a very beginner.I didnt understand anything from what you have said @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: No offense intended, but if you don't know what constructors are or about overloading them then you need to learn basic java before trying to do Android or you are going to have more headaches than normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the constructor of the class Haber:

```
public Haber(String baslik, String kisaAciklama, String tarih,String resimURL){
    super();
    this.baslik = baslik;
    this.kisaAciklama = kisaAciklama;
    this.tarih = tarih;
    this.resimURL = resimURL;
}
```

For `Haber("asdasda","asdasdsa","farfafa")` you need a second constructor like this

```
public Haber(String baslik, String kisaAciklama, String tarih){
    Haber(baslik, kisaAciklama, tarih,"adfadsgsad");
}
```

In this case the first constructor gets called by the second one with `"adfadsgsad"` as default parameter.

Comment: If i want to do something like that : public Haber(String baslik, String kisaAciklama, String tarih, String uzunAciklama){
    Haber(baslik, kisaAciklama, tarih,uzunAciklama);
} Where im going to put this.uzunAciklama = uzunAciklama ?

Comment: `this.uzunAciklama` looks like a class field, that is NOT in your posted code, so it would be the theoretical fifth parameter in a third constructor or you have to modify the first and second one.

Comment: Ohh, i understood everything now.I cant express myself well cause of my english grade but I understood what i was trying to.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh you right, I just copied and pasted it out of his code snippet to show him his class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when you are calling your Haber class
Haber("asdasda","asdasdsa","farfafa", "") ;
So, your last parameter will bee empty

Comment: This is the simpliest solution and works in many cases but I need to learn about constructors etc. Btw Thank  you.